# PHP header file breaks when included in another file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a header file which changes based on if the user is signed in and when I test the header file on its own when I am a logged in user it shows the amount of notifications from the database query. When I include the header in another file it changes the navigation based on the user being logged in or logged out but the query is not working when I var_dump it then it returns NULL. Here is some of the code from the header file.

```
$result =("SELECT * FROM Request WHERE user2='$log_username' AND accepted='0'");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $result);
$rowz = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rowz > 0) {
    $loginLink = '<a href = "user.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href = "request_page.php">Requests <span class="badge">'.$rowz.'</span></a></li>
            <li><a href = "browse_user.php">Browse Users</a></li>
            <li><a href = "upgrade.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href = "logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon-class"></a>';
```

Comment: Have you echoed $log_username before the query to ensure it is the value you expect it to be?

Comment: Where is the variant code?  Show more of the suspects!

Comment: You shouldn't have to make a query on each page-load, just get the information when the user logs in and store everything you need in the session.

Comment: @Quantastical I have validation in place at the top of the page it is included on that will redirect the user to the home page if the $log_username is blank but it does not redirect me. The only thing I can think of is that both the header file and the file I am including it in require the same separate file

Comment: @jeroen I did not think of that, thanks I already set the session for the username and userid

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.